# Excepción Failed to find configured root al intentar obtener URI en Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando obtener la URI de una foto existente para abrir dicha foto en una aplicación externa seleccionada por el usuario.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    @Override
public void onMultimediaClick(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), position + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayList<AbstractMultimediaEntrada> multimediaEntradas = mNota.getEntradasMultimedia();

    File file = new File(multimediaEntradas.get(position).getmPath());

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "itsur.p77a.notaspfinal.fileprovider" , file);
    String mime = getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(uri);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Cuando intenta buscar el URI simplemente lanza la excepción

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: itsur.p77a.notaspfinal, PID: 12538
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1573634695938.jpg
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    at itsur.p77a.notaspfinal.EditNoteFragment.onMultimediaClick(EditNoteFragment.java:528)
    at itsur.p77a.notaspfinal.MultimediaAdapter$MultimediaViewHolder.onClick(MultimediaAdapter.java:46)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21170)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
```

En mi archivo file_paths.xml tengo lo siguiente:

```
<external-files-path name="storage/emulated/0/Android/data/itsur.p77a.notaspfinal/files" path="/" />
```

Eso provoca que todo funcione bien con las fotos tomadas por mi misma aplicación en esa ruta, pero al intentar abrir fotos de otra carpeta me lanza el error.